# Get e-mail header with .js - Outlook Add-IN

Tags: javascript, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins

I'm trying to get some information that is only on header email.
I'm trying to config it on taskpane.js but i didn't found any help about that.

I want to get this information:
Return-Path: xxx
Received: xxxx
X-SID:
X-Originating-IP:
Envelope-To:
etc.

And print it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

taskpone.js doesn't have the feature to get header information.
If you are considering add-in, try this [MHA](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/wa104005406?tab=overview) add-in for outlook.

Comment: Hi,
Do you know any method where can i print the headers without taskapane.js?

I want to create the Add-in just for learn